# How to capitalized first letter of text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

There is some text in a text field. Before setting it to txtfdName, I want to capitalize the first letter.

```
[addrecipe.txtfdName setText:txtfield1.text];
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use **autocapitalizationType** for capital letter of UITextField.

```
txtfield1.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

Comment: It will not work if its simulator or Auto-Capitalisation is turned off from Settings>General>Keyboard>Auto-Capitalisation on iOS/iDevice

Comment: Be aware that this solution doesn't work if auto correction is disabled for text field.

Comment: If you want to capitalize the first letter you should use UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences. Because UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords will capitalize first letter of every word in the text field, not just the first one.

Answer (score 14):

Use this code to capitalized first latter

```
NSString *abc = @"this is test";

abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[abc substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[abc substringFromIndex:1] ];       
NSLog(@"abc = %@",abc);
```

Answer (score 8):

To capitalize the first letter of each word manually in code:

```
NSString* name = [addrecipe.txtfdName setText:txtfield1.text];
name = [name capitalizedString];
```

Answer (score 5):

Use  [autocapitalizationType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputTraits/autocapitalizationType) property of [UITextInputTraits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) protocol which is conform by both `UITextView` and `UITextField`

```
txtfield1.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
txtfield1.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

or you can also try

```
[addrecipe.txtfdName setText:[txtfield1.text capitalizedString]]; // the first character from each word in the receiver changed to its corresponding uppercase value
```

Answer (score 1):

select txtfield1 and go to Attributes Inspector , there is a  Capitalization with a drop down menu and select menu form Following

**Word** : if you select  Word than first character of every word is    Capital

**Sentences** : if you Sentence  than first character of First word of    every sentence  is Capital

**All Characters** : All Characters are Capital

Answer (score 0):

In XCODE 10.0, swift 3, I had to use the following:

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.none
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.sentences
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.allCharacters
```